# Unable to Login through Bitnami Wordpress on AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami, aws-marketplace

I am trying to run AWS on Bitnami on AWS Marketplace. When I try to login I get the following message

```
HTTP POST action is not allowed for policy reasons.
```

How do I rectify this?

PFA Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please help to resolve this issue

Comment: Hello!! Hello!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to login using https. And override the security warning.